# Rails Actionmailer Sending Multiple Recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm having trouble getting Rails to send an email to multiple users at once. I am trying to send a notification to multiple venues signed up to my site when an Enquiry that matches them is approved.

A pending Enquiry has to be approved by admin. The mailer is passed the `@enquiry`, which is when the email is triggered. Shown here in my `Enquiries controller`:

```
def approve
    @enquiry.approve
    redirect_to [:admin, @enquiry], notice: 'Enquiry is approved.'
    SupplierMailer.new_enquiry(@enquiry).deliver
 end
```

In my `Supplier_mailer.rb`, I have this method:

```
    def new_enquiry(enquiry)
      @enquiry = enquiry
      @enquiry.venues.each do |venue|
        mail(to: venue.supplier.user.email, subject: 'You have a new enquiry')
      end
    end
```

Currently, it is only sending to 1 email address, so not looping properly.

Models:

```
Enquiry 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :venues

Supplier
  has_many :venues
  has_one :user
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `new_enquiry` method is supposed to build one email, which is then being send with `deliver` method. The loop work correctly, however every time you're calling mail, you override its previous call, and the method returns the last call.

Instead, first get the list of recipients, and use it as a `to` attribute

```
emails = @enquiry.venues.map {|venue| venue.supplier.user.email}
mail(to: emails, subject: 'You have a new enquiry')
```

If you are not happy with sending other emails to each other, you will need place Mailer action inside the loop:

```
def approve
  @enquiry.approve
  redirect_to [:admin, @enquiry], notice: 'Enquiry is approved.' 
  @enquiry.venues.each do |venue|
    SupplierMailer.new_enquiry(@enquiry, venue).deliver
  end
end

def new_enquiry(enquiry, venue)
  @enquiry = enquiry
  mail(to: venue.supplier.user.email, subject: 'You have a new enquiry')
end
```

Final option is pretty hacky, but provides best interface:

```
class SupplierMailer << ActionMailer::Base

  def self.new_enquiry(enquiry)
    @enquiry = enquiry
    mails = @enquiry.venues.map do |venue|
      mail(to: venue.supplier.user.email, subject: 'You have a new enquiry')
    end
    class << mails
      def deliver
        each(&:deliver)
      end
    end
    mails
  end
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I used the second option you gave, works perfectly.

Comment: Hey guys, I have a similar problem, and wanted to ask a follow up question to this solution. With the class SupplierMailer code how did you get your values for @enquiry.venues.map do |venue| etc... to render on a template. I have a similar setup but I can't get my text.erb file to render properly because the variables inside the array are not instance variables, thus they don't carry over. Did you encounter that problem?